# How do I make a canvas fill up the entire area of a table

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a matching game. I've created a left and right table with elements that are to be matched. The middle table contains a canvas.

However, the canvas only centers itself in the table, leaving a lot of space on top and below of it, making the matching impossible.

Is there anyway to make the canvas fill up the entire area of the table?

[image]

**The Code**

```css
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
table ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="first">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul class="firstleft"></ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul class="firstright"></ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ngkghxja/

Comment: Please provide a snippet or jsfiddle of your code (including css)

Comment: i didn't add html or css at first cos it wouldn't be of much use. now you can judge for youself to see whether it helped

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note the canvas comes with two sizes - the size of the drawing surface, and the size of the canvas element itself. You want to set the size of the drawing surface to the dimensions of the parent `td` element, by changing the canvas `width` and `height` properties.

With jQuery, you can do something like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var $td = $('canvas').parent();
canvas.width = $td.width();
canvas.height = $td.height();
```

Without jQuery, you have to use the parentNode's clientWidth and clientHeight instead:

```
var td = canvas.parentNode;
canvas.width = td.clientWidth;
canvas.height = td.clientHeight;
```

Comment: You need to specify the variable for the canvas element in pure JavaScript as well:

    var canvas = getElementById('myCanvas')

Comment: Yes, that's necessary in both cases

Comment: If you want the canvas to resize when the window resizes, you have to remove the canvas from its parent, store the parent size, and then add the canvas back into the parent